# Compare date in where clause of manual query using parameterised query in Laravel not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, datetime

I am developing a Laravel 5.2 web application. I am retrieving record from database according to user input date that is compared to timestamp in database. I am running manual query using parameterized query because the query is too complicated.

I retrieve records like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usres`";
$sql .= " WHERE DATE(`created_at`) = '2015-04-04'";
DB::select($sql);

$date = '2015-04-04';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usres`";
$sql .= " WHERE DATE(`created_at`) = '{$date}'";
DB::select($sql);
```

As you can see above, I did not use parameterized query. `created_at` is timestamp and so I converted it into date. The above query is working. It is retrieving the correct data.

I retrieve using parameterized query like this

```
$date = '2015-04-04';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usres`";
$sql .= " WHERE DATE(`created_at`) = ?";
DB::select($sql,[$date]);
```

The above code is not working. As you can see, I used parameterized query. I tried like below as well.

```
$date = "'".2015-04-04."'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usres`";
$sql .= " WHERE DATE(`created_at`) = ?";
DB::select($sql,[$date]);


$date = "2015-04-04";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usres`";
$sql .= " WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`,'%Y-%m-%d') = ?";
DB::select($sql,[$date]);
```

This is not working as well.

Why it is not retrieving data when I use parameterized query?

Comment: Why not query it all? LIKE `DB::select("SELECT * FROM usres WHERE DATE(created_at) = '2015-04-04' "')`

Comment: It is not secure. Right? It can easily be SQL-Injected.

Comment: I think you will not have problems in that because laravel use PDO and if you correctly setup the datatypes in your database.

Comment: If not sure. I do not want to go for it. Is it sure please?

Comment: Can i see your server side validation for date?